# Who is Mr. T and where does he work?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, geography, english

**Update:**

To encourage completion of this puzzle, I've added spoilers to indicate any correct or incorrect answers so far. Also, it's possible to work on Part 2 while Part 1 is incomplete or partly incorrect, and then go back and fill or correct answers to Part 1.

**Part 1:**

Write each answer as ONEWORD, without spaces, punctuation or abbreviating. Some questions may have more than one answer when taken alone, but only certain answers will work with respect to the whole puzzle.

1: Where can you find the easternmost traffic light in the United States, including territories and possessions?

> (Not ALASKA)

2: What is the longest irregular verb?

> MISUNDERSTAND, with credit to Kramii

3: Based on what you saw last month (December 2020), which is the most visible planet in our solar system?

> EARTH, with credit to ralphmerridew

4: Which four consecutive letters in the alphabet can be rearranged to form a familiar word, with each letter appearing at least once?

> RSTU, with credit to ralphmerridew

5: What’s a lung disease that comes from breathing in very fine ash and sand dust?

> PNEUMONOULTRAMICROSCOPICSILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS, with credit to Benja

6: Name an 11-letter monosyllabic word.

> SQUIRRELLED, with credit to Benja

7: Which two letters from the English alphabet are the least frequently used in the Spanish language?

> KW, with credit to Kramii

8: What word means “to exalt”, and has an anagram that means “to instruct”?

**Part 2:**

145 46 365 415 32 43 82 58 81 48 24 22 105 96 58 27 21 275 17 16

**Part 3:**

Who is Mr. T and where does he work?

**Notes:**

Partial answers are encouraged, as this may be tricky to solve alone, but the checkmark will go to whomever answers all parts correctly. When you’ve got it all figured out, copy from others if needed (and give credit) to form a complete answer.

Comment: How do i format an answer to make it so people dont have to see any questions i answer if they dont want to

Comment: @Benja You can put the content inside [spoilers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup). The syntax can in some cases be annoying, but generally it's `>! your text`. If you need a multi-line spoiler, you either need to add two spaces or a `<br>` at the end of the line.

Answer (score 7):

I believe I have all of this now:

Credit to Kramii, ralphmerridew, Benja and Stiv for most of the answers to Part 1.

## Part 1

### 1

> The easternmost (by longitude) U.S. territory/possession that has any traffic lights is the Northern Mariana Islands, but that doesn't work with part 2.
>  So the question is probably asking for **Saint Croix** in the U.S. Virgin Islands, with credit to Stiv.

### 2

> MISUNDERSTAND, with credit to Kramii

### 3

> EARTH, with credit to ralphmerridew

### 4

> RSTU, with credit to ralphmerridew

### 5

> PNEUMONOULTRAMICROSCOPICSILICOVOLCANOCONIOSIS, with credit to Benja

### 6

> SQUIRRELLED, with credit to Benja

### 7

> KW, with credit to Kramii

### 8

> **DEIFY**, which is an anagram of EDIFY

## Part 2

On to the numbers:

> Here, we need to split every number into two parts by separating the final
>  digit.
>  The final digit identifies an answer from part 1, and the digit(s) before it indicate a letter in that answer:
>
> ```
>  14 5  M
>  4  6  I
>  36 5  N
>  41 5  I
>  3  2  S
>  4  3  T
>  8  2  R
>  5  8  Y
>  8  1  O
>  4  8  F
>  2  4  S
>  2  2  I
>  10 5  L
>  9  6  L
>  5  8  Y
>  2  7  W
>  2  1  A
>  27 5  L
>  1  7  K
>  1  6  S
> ```
>
> Putting those together gives us:
>  **Ministry of silly walks**

## Part 3

> So Mr. T is Mr. Teabag (played by John Cleese) in the famous Monty Python [Ministry of Silly Walks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eCLp7zodUiI) sketch

Comment: For number 1 [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Croix) may be the answer you're missing... ("as measured from the center of the continental United States, ignoring the westernmost of the Aleutian Islands of Alaska just west of the 180th meridian")

Answer (score 2):

> I believe that the theme is related to being extreme (easternmost, longest, most visible, etc.) so the answers that i came up with for some of the questions are: 5.pneumonoultramicroscopicsilicovolcanoconiosis(the longest word in any major dictionary)
>  6. squirrelled

Answer (score 2):

> 1: Probably ALASKA; it extends westward into the eastern hemisphere
>  3: From my experiences, EARTH
>  4: rstu => RUST

Answer (score 2):

2. The longest irregular verb I can find has 13 letters:

> Misunderstand

7. The letters are:

> K and W